# jQuery on change don't return attribute value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Have problem to display select on change attribute id.

PHP:

```
<form action="" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="kategorijos" id="kategorijos" class="category form-control" onchange="fetch_select_category(this.value);">
            <option value=""></option>
            FOREACH
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <fieldset disabled>
            <select id="disabledSelect" name="subcategories" class="subcategory form-control" onchange="fetch_select_product(this.value);" required>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Subcategory</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <td><input type="text" name="gramai" class="form-control" value=""></td>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="kalb">
        <input type='text' name='1[]' value="-" disabled>
        <input type='text' name='12[]' value="-" disabled>
        <input type='text' name='123[]' value="-" disabled>
        <input type='text' name='1234[]' value="-" disabled>
    </div>
</form>
```

My jquery code:

```
$("select").on('change', function() {
    var status = $('select').attr('id');
    alert(status); 
});

var categoryId = 0;
var category = 0;
var product = 0;
var disableId = 0;

$("#add").click(function () {
    categoryId = categoryId + 1;
    category = category + 1;
    product = product + 1;
    disableId = disableId + 1;

    $("#item").append('<div class="col-xs-12"><form action="" 
        class="form-inline"><div class="form-group"><select name="kategorijos" 
        **....... same code as above (php)**
    });
```

When I select the first row it alerts value. But then I add new row with add button, and then change second select the alert don't work, and I don't get the select id. Where can be the problem? Maybe it doesn't work with append html ?

Comment: Where is the HTML element with the id "#add" you are selecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [**event delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically generated element and also use `this` instead of `'select'` to get the `id` of dropdown.

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
    var status = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(status); 
});
```